# How to display an image title below the image with SASS?

Tags: css, image, sass

Given an image has its `title` parameter specified, how do I make it visible on the page below the image? E.g. by copying it to `&:after` content (I don't know the syntax for this, I'm using SASS for the first time).

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot achieve that using CSS, and thus, also not using SASS, Less, Stylus or what have you.

The reason for this is that `::before` and `::after` can only be used on elements that can have `content` (which is what is between the opening tag and the closing tag).

Example:

```
<div>
  content
</div>
```

In this example the browser can insert `::before` and `::after` like this:

```
<div>
  ::before
  content
  ::after
</div>
```

An `img` tag cannot have `content`, though, because it simply does not have a closing tag:

```
<img src="path/to/my/img.png" title="my image title" />
```

As you can see there is no content, and thus, no positions to insert `::before` and `::after`.

Other elements you cannot use `::before` and `::after`  on:

```
<input /> <!-- doesn't matter which type -->
<br />
<hr />
```

Comment: @Ivan finally ... according this answer the solution is: wrap the image in `div` and use `:before\:after` to the `div`

Comment: Which still won't help if you need the `title` value from the `img` tag.

Comment: @VXp Sure, but what does that have to do with this?

Comment: Maybe not using self-closing tags.

Comment: And what would that change? `<img></img>` is invalid in HTML 5 as well. HTML 5 just allows to omit the `/` in `<img />`.

Comment: <img>, <input>, <br>, <hr> etc. <img /> ... are not invalid, just unnecessary for a while now. Don't know why you've added them.

Comment: You don't get it. I have listed elements that cannot have `content`. You are talking about omitting the trailing `/`. **Those two things are not related at all.**

Comment: I know, exactly, don't know why you've added them since they are useless. I'm not talking about the issue...

Comment: Well, I cannot help you with that then. The answer says *Other elements you cannot use ::before and ::after on:* - how is that useless, or unclear?

Comment: It's you who doesn't get it. I'm just talking about not using the self-closing tags anymore, because they are not necessary since HTML5, and nothing else. Old school habit I guess.

Comment: The trailing slashes are not useless. You might want to make up your mind on XML.

Comment: What does XML have to do with it?

Comment: I'm not here to educate you on that.

Comment: Didn't know he's using XML, probably forgot to add it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180142/discussion-between-connexo-and-vxp).